# decision tree and maximum depth

Tags: decision-tree

I am new to decision tree model and have a seemingly stupid question. Say I have a decision of which max_depth is set to be 20. Does it mean that the tree has to be 20 layers deep or any integer smaller than 20 is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you precise `max_depth = 20`, then the tree can have leaves anywhere between 1 and 20 layers deep.
That's why they put `max_` next to `depth` ;) or else it would've been just `depth`

Answer (score 0):

It can have any number between 1 to 20, it depends on at which level the hypothetical model performs best.For more details on decision tree refer this.
https://infocenter.informationbuilders.com/wf80/topic/pubdocs/RStat16/source/topic47.htm